# Showing seperate output windows in Visual Studio 2015 when debugging multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When debugging a large solution configured to run four projects, it's quite irritating for all the debug logs to be presented in a single 'Output' window in VS2015 - with no identifier for which project a specific log message came from.

Is there a way to split these logs out so they are easier to process? Or some kind of extension?

Comment: Ah, logging. Are these logs from your code? You might need to think of a better way to disambiguate from the text of the log.